# Drawback of not calling fs.exist before fs.rename?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, file, fs

I need to rename a file if it exists. Currently I'm just using the code below

```
fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) { /*don't care*/ })
```

Is there a drawback to this in terms of performance or other problems instead of doing fs.exists() or fs.stat() first before rename? I feel like if I need to check if it exists then rename, that's 2 operations, but if i just rename, it's 1 operation.

I couldn't find the code implementation of this function, but I know in certain programming languages an exception is thrown and handled when file doesn't exist and it can be taxing on the system, just trying to see if that's the case here as well. I work on an extremely large system with trillions of requests, so every nanosecond count.

Comment: `fs.rename` without checking `fs.stat`

Comment: You could write both variants and test them for time consumation etc. As fs.rename (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) implements http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html an exception should be no big deal. Nevertheless I would go for checking and renaming. On the other hand I think that @DanD. made a very good point.

Comment: Looks like we don't have a consensus here. In certain programming languages an exception is very taxing on the system, so I was just checking to see if that's an issue here. I guess I'll write few tests to find out.

Comment: @DanD. not fs.exists() specifically, it's replaced with fs.access() or fs.stat(), main point of the question is to ask about whether checking for existence is slower or faster.